# Difficulty detecting an empty list

Tags: python, list, printing, palindrome

I need to take a list of words and return a list of the palindromes found in the original list. I have got the code that works to do that, but if the list doesn't need to contain any palindromes it needs to print a statement saying none found.

I have looked at other questions/answers on here on how to check if a list is empty, but I couldn't find any that were relevant to my function, where I'm creating the list in a for loop, and needing to check whether the list I'm creating contains anything. The examples I found were only checking pre made lists.

This is the code that works to create the list of palindromes in the format needed:

```
def is_palindrome(words):

    """Returns the palindromes from a list of words."""
    print("\nThe following palindromes were found: ")
    for word in words:
        if word == word[::-1] and len(word) >= 3:
            print(' -', word)
```

And this was my attempt:

```
def is_palindrome(words):

    """Returns the palindromes from a list of words."""
    print("\nThe following palindromes were found: ")
    palindromes = []
    for word in words:
        if word == word[::-1] and len(word) >= 3:
            palindromes.append(word)
            if palindromes != []:
                print(' -', word)
            else:
                print('None found...')
```

But the 'none found' is never printed.

Advice as to where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: An empty list equates to False, so you just need `if palindromes:`

Comment: Is there any wrong with the solutions?

Comment: This function prints the palindromes, but it returns `None`. Isn't it supposed to return a list of the palindromes?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for word in words:
    if word == word[::-1] and len(word) >= 3:
        palindromes.append(word)
        print('palindrome - ',word)
if len(palindromes)==0:
    print('None found...')
```

OR:

```
for word in words:
    if word == word[::-1] and len(word) >= 3:
        palindromes.append(word)
        print('palindrome - ',word)
if not palindromes:
    print('None found...')
```

Comment: The first method is advised against generally, according to PEP8, though it works well.

Comment: @NChauhan Yeah agree with you, the first example **shouldn't be used**.

Comment: @U9-Forward Both the methods are acceptable FYI check docs of [`PEP8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#programming-recommendations)

Answer (score 1):

Just do `not`:

```
palindromes = []
for word in words:
    if word == word[::-1] and len(word) >= 3:
        palindromes.append(word)
if not palindromes:
    print('None found...')
```